# Adding to full text catalogue without full rebuild

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, rebuild, full-text-catalog

I have a product list in SQL Server with a large number of rows (100K +).  We perform a regular full text search on the table to find products that contain a keyword. Upon adding a new product it is very slow to drop and recreate the full text catalogue to include the new part.

Is there any way I can add a single row to the full text catalogue without having to rebuild the entire catalogue?

This would need to be supported on SQL Server 2012 to current.

Comment: The full text index should keep itself up-to-date when you add new rows.

Comment: Is there an option or setting that needs to be enabled for this to happen?

Comment: It's the change_tracking option, set per FT index in the catalog

Comment: That's it sorted. Many thanks.  I you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it so you get credit :)

Comment: Cheers, no worries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a full text index within the catalog, you can specify the `change_tracking` option as auto (default), manual, or off.
Auto will automatically propagate changes; manual requires you to run an alter index statement to update the index, and off does not track changes.

NB: `updatetext` & `writetext` operations are not picked up by change tracking.

You can check the `change_tracking` option for an index in the SSMS GUI or the `sys.fulltext_indexes` view.

You can change the setting for an index in SSMS or with an `alter fulltext index... set change_tracking [option]` statement.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188359.aspx

Comment: The alter statement is `ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ... SET CHANGE_TRACKING` not simply `ALTER INDEX ...`